# Avoid redundant author and title in consequent citation

Tags: bibtex

I have different bibliographic entry for the same work of an author edited different times.

Using `\cite` for these entries I need to avoid redundant author name and title, replacing them with a line "–". I’m bound to use `ext-verbose-trad2` style and `memoir`  class.

Here a code example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openright, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=ext-verbose-trad2]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{1906_Flor_SlovoNaSvjatNed,
    author = {Gualtieroni, P.},
    date = {1906-04-02},
    journal = {Narod},
    month = {4},
    number = {1},
    pages = {3},
    title = {O duchovnoe istine},
    year = {1906}}

@article{1907_Flor_NatchZhizn_Christ,
    author = {Gualtieroni, P.},
    journal = {Christianin},
    number = {4},
    pages = {705-709},
    title = {O duchovnoe istine},
    volume = {2},
    year = {1907}}

@book{1907_Flor_NatchZhizn,
    address = {Sergej Posad},
    author = {Gualtieroni, P.},
    publisher = {tip. Lavra},
    title = {O duchovnoe istine},
    year = {1907}}

@inbook{2018_Flor_NatchZhizn,
    crossref = {2018_Flor_BogosTrud},
    pages = {515-518},
    title = {O duchovnoe istine}}

@book{2018_Flor_BogosTrud,
    author = {Gualtieroni, P.},
    editor = {Brambilla, G.},
    publisher = {Florenziana},
    title = {Lavori teosofici 1902--1909},
    year = {2018}}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[1906] \emph{On the spiritual truth}\\ {\footnotesize \cite{1906_Flor_SlovoNaSvjatNed}; cfr. also
\cite{1907_Flor_NatchZhizn_Christ,1907_Flor_NatchZhizn}; recently reprinted in:
\cite{2018_Flor_NatchZhizn}.}
\end{description}    


\end{document}
```

Which gives as an output:

[image]

I wish a result as this:

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us more about your actual use case here? The way the `\cite`s are used here makes me thing it might be more appropriate to use a (filtered) `\printbibliography` call here, where you'd get the dash for free.

Comment: I uploaded a better code example to better specify what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Using `style=authoryear` gives me the following output.

```tex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openright, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    
    @article{1906_Flor_SlovoNaSvjatNed,
        author = {Gualtieroni, P.},
        date = {1906-04-02},
        journal = {Narod},
        month = {4},
        number = {1},
        pages = {3},
        title = {Title of the beautiful composition},
        year = {1906}}
    
    @article{1907_Flor_NatchZhizn_Christ,
        author = {Gualtieroni, P.},
        journal = {Christianin},
        number = {4},
        pages = {705-709},
        title = {Title of the beautiful composition},
        volume = {2},
        year = {1907}}
    
    @book{1907_Flor_NatchZhizn,
        address = {Sergej Posad},
        author = {Gualtieroni, P.},
        publisher = {tip. Lavra},
        title = {Title of the beautiful composition},
        year = {1907}}
    
    @inbook{2018_Flor_NatchZhizn,
        crossref = {2018_Flor_BogosTrud},
        pages = {515-518},
        title = {Title of the beautiful composition}}
    
    @book{2018_Flor_BogosTrud,
        author = {Gualtieroni, P.},
        editor = {Brambilla, G.},
        publisher = {Florenziana},
        title = {Lavori teosofici 1902--1909},
        year = {2018}}
    
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
    
    \cite{1906_Flor_SlovoNaSvjatNed}\par
    \cite{1907_Flor_NatchZhizn_Christ}\par
    \cite{1907_Flor_NatchZhizn}\par
    \cite{2018_Flor_NatchZhizn}\par
    
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

Citations:

[image]

Bibliography:

[image]

Comment: I’m actually obliged to use `ext-verbose-trad2` style. Moreover, my question is about the `\cite` command output, rather than the bibliography. I’ll specify more clearly  these things in my question.

Comment: Oh, I see! No doubt I was wondering why you didn't have a `\printbibliography` in the MWE :).